# Associating a child model in a polymorphic relationship causes an infinite loop?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a base `Message` class for an inbox using a polymorphic relationship to attach custom message types which all implement the same interface and behave differently in views based on their type. Display of that all works swimmingly, but I hit a snag when I tried to actually add these with code.

This is the Message class:

```
<?php

class Message extends Eloquent {
    public function author() {
        $this->belongsTo("User", "author_id");
    }

    public function recipient() {
        $this->belongsTo("User", "recipient_id");
    }

    public function message() {
        $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

The model that I attach to `message()` implements `MessageInterface`, So I thought I'd be able to make a quick helper to attach this model's relationship via `Message::send()`:

```
public static function send(MessageInterface $message, User $to, User $from) {
    if (! $message->exists)
        $message->save();

    $parent = new static;

    $parent->author()->associate($from);
    $parent->recipient()->associate($to);
    $parent->message()->associate($message); // line that errors

    return $parent->save();
}
```

But this ends up throwing what looks to be infinite recursion at me:

```
FatalErrorException: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

This is the `studly` function, and from some searching it seems to happen when two models reference each other.

The Schema for the messages table is:

```
$table->increments("id");
$table->integer("message_id")->unsigned();
$table->string("message_type");
$table->integer("recipient_id")->unsigned();
$table->integer("author_id")->unsigned();
$table->timestamps();
```

Am I just doing something *really* wrong, here? I've looked through the `morphTo` method call in [the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L724) and tried seeing if reflection is the problem here (grabbing the function name and snake casing it), but I can't seem to find what is happening. The [associate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphTo.php#L96) method call is just setting attributes and getting the class name for `message_type`, then returning a relationship.

There's no useful information in the error; it's a `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException` with no context.

I'm running Laravel 4.1

Comment: paste the stack trace, for example here http://bin.laravel.io/

Comment: @deczo ...there isn't one. The trace is literally just laravel's error shutdown with a blank trace, and then `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException`.

Comment: You have `debug=true` in app/config/app.php ?

Comment: @deczo of course: http://puu.sh/8Vf88/1645cf0f90.png

Comment: What version of the framework it is?

Comment: If you install php5-xdebug on your system you should be able to see the stack trace of the fatal error.

Comment: The thing is, before 4.1.29 (or 4.2) associate is not working on `morphTo`, check it here https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4249